# How to download MikTeX from a specific download site?

Tags: miktex

Trying to download MikTeX. Seems the download progress goes so that it uses the "nearest" available download site. But I have had problems already when downloading new packages: The site ftp.funet.fi can't be connected. This happened all the time until I was wise enough to change the download site to a swedish one via the MikTeX console. But now my hard drive broke and I have to download MikTeX again - via the terminal commands. But now, the same problem: ftp.funet.fi can't be connected. What commands can I use in the terminal to use some other - functioning - download site? Can you please help me?

Comment: MikTeX Console -> Settings -> Package are installed from: click on "change" and then in the open window click on "Next" (at bottom of window) which will open window with list of servers from which you can download desired Remote Package Repository.

Comment: OK. I found now how to download TeXLive from a specific download site (repository seems to be the right term!). So I will start to use TeXLive. Hopefully I'll be able to configure it to be used with TexMaker;)

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for the answer! Yes, I think I could have done that, but at the moment I don't have the MikTeX Console available, because I have to load all the programs again to this new hard disk. I really would have needed the commands to be used in the terminal.

Comment: Actually, I did find the right directory trees - for MikTeX and TexLive - from ftp.funet.fi. Can it be possible that the install program searches the files from wrong location?

Comment: Can't you  use a download manager such as Filezilla?

Comment: how to use the command line to install miktex is described here: https://docs.miktex.org/manual/setupwiz.html. There is an option to set the repository.